# Would painters tape come off without damaging paint years later?

Tags: paint, adhesive, tape

I'm trying to apply some sound insulation to a sliding glass door in a rental apartment. The glue on the insulation strip feels pretty hardcore and would certainly take off the paint from the doorway that I want to stick it to once it comes off.

Painters tape however not at all, I did a little patch test and it came off leaving the surface exactly like its surrounding. I figured then that I could just put down some painters tape first and stick the insulation strip on the tape rather than the paint directly. Question is though, would this hold true a year from now? Two years?

Comment: This question is unanswerable as it depends on product, surface integrity, and environmental conditions.

Comment: I think you'd be better off painting the stuck-on area with a known color (e.g. Behr Ultra Pure White) and just sticking directly to the tape.  You can get more UPW (or whatever color) and repaint in the future when you remove the insulation.

Comment: don't expect it to come off easily

Comment: Thanks to everybody for their consideration, for now I've opted for "delicate" painters tape. There were multiple brands offering this type of product, I went with Tesa since theirs seemed the delicatest based on me probing it with a finger. I'll be back with an update as to how it went a year or two from now.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely not. Painters tape only removes easily (on a good substrate — see below) during a particular period of time. You’ll find the listed time in the product information.

Caveat about substrates: poorly bonded layers or uncured coatings can pull off regardless of how long or short the tape time is.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from a (temporary) truly awful stench when applying in the versions I've tried, "Removable caulking" (*e.g.* Dap Seal & Peel, no endorsement implied) may be a good choice for a removable adhesive with less chance of damage than dried up masking tape. I have used it for winter weather-sealing and removed it later with no issues.

Poster adhesive (*e.g.* Blu-Tack, no endorsement implied) would be another possible option.

If the paint is not in good condition, even these options may lift poorly attached paint.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on the type of surface that the tape is stuck to.  However from real world experience, over time, the glue on painters tape becomes hard and dries out. When removed it will leave the surface damaged in some spots and glue residue stuck in other spots.

In my case the tape was on a very old anodized aluminum sliding door frame for about 9 months.
It was a pain to clean off the tape residue. I had to sand and repaint the frame. More work than I anticipated, but in the end the door looked great.

You may want to remove the tape about every 3 months or so and re apply new tape to keep the door from being damaged.

Answer (score 2):

Find a way to to stick the insulation to the glass part of the door (EG use RTV silicone). It's much easier to scrape a glass surface clean than it is to remove old tape from a painted surface.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd rather not, the glass has a layer of frosted plastic on both sides which I'm afraid to damage. I figured in the worst case scenario I could fix the white paint of the doorway but I'd have no idea how to fix the plastic on the glass if it got damaged.